# GNOME can't login after suspend

Tags: 16.04, lightdm, ubuntu-gnome

I can't login to my account after GNOME suspend. I'm typing password correct, but it shows "Incorrect password". Switching language doesn't help. I must click on "Switch user" and login through LightDM. I'm using Ubuntu 16.04. Did anyone experience this problem? How can I fix it?

Comment: I have a variant of the same problem. It happened once I manually upgraded the kernel to 4.13.8. I'm also using 16.04 and Gnome3. The only thing I could do was Crtl+Alt+F2 and `sudo reboot`